# Strings Binary Search Tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have this Binary Search Tree Question where I will need to place the words in the order they appear in this sentence - *Maths is hard and I don't want to learn* in standard dictionary ordering.

I am not sure if I have placed this correctly as I am comparing it with the first letter of each word. So if the letter of the word of before M, it will be placed on the left hand side while letter after M will be placed on the right hand side.

Currently I am not very sure how I should place the word *I* but at the same time can I check if the way of how I am placing those words accordingly to its first letter the correct approach to do so?

[image: BST]

Comment: In a dictionary "I" is before is thus "I" should be in the left part of "is". Also "to" is after "Math"

Comment: So can I say that "I" is 'smaller' because there are no second letter within its word to compare against "is"? Okay, for the latter part of your answer, it should be "Maths" >> "to" >> "want", all on the right hand side?

Comment: yes and yes. There should be 'want' on the right of 'Maths' and 'to' on the left of 'want' because math<to<want